# OpenGl Solid Cube in C++

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to draw a solid cube in C++ using OpenGl feature but I want to draw it at a desired position such as `glVertex3f(20,5,-35)`. How can I draw a solid cube at the given position?

Comment: 1. What have you tried? (show us code!) 
2. Where specifically are you having trouble?

Comment: to add to what tzaman said http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

glTranslatef(x, y, z). Google it, I think there are 2D versions as well. But this translates the reference frame off the stack. If more complex transformation need to be set up you will need to call glpopmatrix and glpushmatrix. Careful of spelling and usage on those.

Answer (score 2):

To match your question and to draw a cube in OpenGL (compatibility profile) you can use this code:

```
    void drawCube(float x, float y, float z) 
    {
    glBegin(GL_QUADS); 
    glVertex3f(-1.0f+x, -1.0f+y, -1.0f+z);
    glVertex3f(1.0f+x, -1.0f+y, -1.0f+z);
    glVertex3f(1.0f+x, 1.0f+y, -1.0f+z);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f+x, 1.0f+y, -1.0f+z);

    glVertex3f(-1.0f+x, -1.0f+y, -1.0f+z);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f+x, -1.0f+y, 1.0f+z);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f+x, 1.0f+y, -1.0f+z);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f+x, 1.0f+y, 1.0f+z);

    glVertex3f(-1.0f+x, -1.0f+y, -1.0f+z);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f+x, -1.0f+y, 1.0f+z);
    glVertex3f(1.0f+x, -1.0f+y, 1.0f+z);
    glVertex3f(1.0f+x, -1.0f+y, -1.0f+z);

    glVertex3f(-1.0f+x, -1.0f+y, 1.0f+z);
    glVertex3f(1.0f+x, -1.0f+y, 1.0f+z);
    glVertex3f(1.0f+x, 1.0f+y, 1.0f+z);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f+x, 1.0f+y, 1.0f+z);

    glVertex3f(-1.0f+x, -1.0f+y, 1.0f+z);
    glVertex3f(1.0f+x, -1.0f+y, 1.0f+z);
    glVertex3f(1.0f+x, 1.0f+y, 1.0f+z);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f+x, 1.0f+y, 1.0f+z);

    glVertex3f(-1.0f+x, 1.0f+y, -1.0f+z);
    glVertex3f(-1.0f+x, 1.0f+y, 1.0f+z);
    glVertex3f(1.0f+x, 1.0f+y, 1.0f+z);
    glVertex3f(1.0f+x, 1.0f+y, -1.0f+z);

    glEnd();
     }
```

**I do not recommend this function**, use instead the [`glTranslatef(x, y, z)`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTranslate.xml) solution discribed in another answer. Like this function:

```
    void drawCube(float x, float y, float z) 
    {
        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(x, y, z);

        glBegin(GL_QUADS); 
        glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f ,-1.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);

        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

        glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

        glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f ,1.0f );
        glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

        glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
        glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
        glEnd();

        glPopMatrix();
    }
```

This function is far from being perfect, but it should suffice. Happy coding!

Comment: I recommend using glut if possible. They have a function which can easily make a solid or wire cube. glutSolidCobe(glDouble size);